# Como gestionar sesiones en JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, sesiones

Hola amigos soy nuevo en JSF, me gustaria saber como se gestionan las sesiones, ya que tengo una pequeña pagina que estoy haciendo por ahora he creado un login que accede a una pagina inicio y me carga una lista de registros, el problema es que al entrar desde otra maquina puedo entrar a la pagina de inicio y ver igual la lista de los registros cargados cuando no deberia verla porque no me he logueado en esa maquina, estoy usando @SessionScoped y GlassFish como servidor, les agredezco mucho su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Hola @Aldana podrías confirma si tu Proyecto es JSF puro o lo estas mezclado con Spring.

Comment: Hola Roberto gracias por responder, si es JSF puro nada de Spring mi problema es con las sesiones estoy utilizando el alcance de @SessionScoped mira tengo un login que envia a una pagina inicio y en esa pagina inicio tengo una tablita donde muestro unos registros, el login funciona bien y todo el detalle es que si entro desde otro navegador a la ruta inicio deberia de pedirme iniar sesion y no mostrar los registros pero no sucede eso, veo los registros siempre como si me hubiese loggeado.

Comment: En este caso entiendo que ya validadas que la session este activa para mostrar la pagina, lo siguiente es aclara si cuando dices otros navegador te refieres a un usuario en Chrome y otro en Firefox por ejemplo o en 2 pestañas distintas del mismo navegador.

Comment: He de hecho no, no estoy validando la sesión tienes algún ejemplo que me compartas por favor y si correcto a eso me refiero un login en Chrome y otro en Firefox o desde otra maquina apuntando a la dirección de mi maquina donde tengo corriendo GlassFish

Comment: La forma mas simple de validar la session es utilizando el tag `preRenderView`, en esta web te enseñan un ejemplo básico de como se valida si la session esta activa. https://turreta.com/2017/08/01/jsf-check-user-logged-prerenderview/  esto lo tienes que validar en cada una de las paginas.

Comment: Excelente probare con eso, te agradezco mucho Roberto por tu ayuda con esto, saludos.